Downloading Excel file from ASP.NET Web API 2.0 seems to download as text, not binary
I am trying to create an Excel file in my ASP.NET app and then download it through a Web API 2.0 controller (I am not using .NET Core).
I know that I have created the Excel file fine because in the controller code below, you can see that I am writing the spreadsheet out to a file and returning it. The file is 2k and loads into Excel.
The download is 3k and does not load. I am thinking that somehow the binary file is being treated as ascii by the browser and it is doing line ending conversion on it. I have to verify that, but the file lengths are definitely different.
Here is my controller code:
[HttpPost]
[IsAjaxRequest]
[Route("{eventId}/Session/{sessionId}/Participants/spreadsheet")]
[ResponseType(typeof(string))]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetParticipantsSpreadsheet(int eventId, int sessionId)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    {
        var result = await ApiClubEventManage.GetParticipantsSpreadsheetAsync(stream, eventId, sessionId, GetCurrentUser(), IsUserSiteAdmin(), SystemClock.Instance, getDb());
        stream.Position = 0;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("/file.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        stream.CopyTo(fs);
        fs.Close();

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StreamContent(stream) };

        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = result.Data, Size = stream.Length };
        response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue { NoCache = true, NoStore = true, MustRevalidate = true };

        return response;
    }
}

Any suggestions? All the search results look just like this.
There is definitely some conversion going on. Here is the first 32 bytes of data in the file that was written directly to the file system and works.

And here are the first 43 bytes to get to the same character in the file when it is downloaded through Chrome and Web API 2.0:

Things are good until it hits the 0x60 byte and then that gets modified.
Edit 2:
I am looking at the request in chrome and I see that the Request Headers indicate Accept as application/json, text/plain, */*.
I am wondering if that is the issue. I would have thought that */* caught everything, but I now wondering if the conversion is happening because of this request header setting.

The Web API side was working just fine. The problem turned out to be on the Axios / javascript side of things.
I am using this javascript library to extract the file from the response that axios fetches. I did't heed the warning on the libraries website of ensuring that axios is informed to request a blob when downloading. Once that was done, the file came down with exactly the same data that was being saved to disk by the controller.
